# Javascript date format issue with "Month date, year hour:minutes am"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking for JavaScript method to change below date format to seconds.

July 16, 2017 00:05 am

Below full format (**I need only Month date, year hour:minutes am**. Please let me know to remove unwanted)

```
var date = new Date();
```

it displays "`Sun Jul 16 2017 00:05:50 GMT+0800 (SGT)`"

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: You want format to seconds, and then you are asking for only Month date, year hour:minutes am?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
console.log(getFormattedDate(new Date()));


function getFormattedDate(date) {
  var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
  ];

  var year = date.getFullYear();

  var day = date.getDate().toString();
  day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;

  var hour = date.getHours().toString();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes().toString();

  var ampm = hour >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';

  return monthNames[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + day + ', ' + year + ' ' + hour + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
}
```

Comment: `I need only Month date, year hour:minutes am`

Comment: `Looking for JavaScript method to change below date format to seconds.`

Comment: Well that's a bit confusing when he's also asking for what I posted. How does this deserve a downvote? Clearly answers the question.